# Word that means "annoyingly sheepish"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the behavior of someone who is avoidant or bashful about performing some task, with a pejorative connotation; like timid, but annoyingly so.

A: I know you can do this. You have the talent and the education, and it will only benefit you to perform this task.

B: You're right...but I don't feel confident in my abilities.

A: You are starting to get on my nerves. You are being so ____!

Comment: Thank you for giving a set up in the premise for your example sentence.

Comment: The problem here is the use of **so** in the third example. Any number of adjectives could be used that, *on their own*, don't mean *excessively* or *annoyingly*. But by using the word **so**, you are licensing their use. However, the question also says that it's asking for a word that includes a pejorative connotation *in the word itself*. So, which is it? If the word has such a connotation, then the use of **so** shouldn't be required. If **so** *is* required, then there are far more possible words. (I have a great one, but it only works when used alongside **so**.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks for the response. That's an interesting perspective; I hadn't thought of cases when "so" itself would suggest a pejorative connotation. I'd like to know which word you're thinking of. That said, I don't think there is a problem in the formulation of the question, unless I wrote something that precludes the use of a word meaning "annoyingly sheepish" in this context.

Comment: @KusuguriZeme I'd actually been thinking of **miliqetoast**, which has now been provided in one of the answers. I wouldn't say that *you are being milquetoast* would be used pejoratively. Instead, it would only really work with *you are being **so** milquetoast.* (The existing answer does, however, give two other words that don't need to have **so** in front of them.)

Answer (score 2):

You could describe that kind of person as **[spineless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spineless)**.

A spineless person lacks determination and is not willing to take risks. So is the case in your example:

> B: You're right...but I don't feel confident in my abilities.

You could say *B is spineless*.

**[Lily-livered](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lily-livered)** could also be used for such kind of person but it's a bit old-fashioned.

Informal words such as *yellow-bellied, mousy, or chicken* could also be used to describe such kind of person.

*Milquetoast* is also a good word for this.

Cambridge English dictionary defines **[milquetoast](http://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/milquetoast)** as:

> a shy, nervous person with a weak character, usually a man.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions. The second one requires a slight change in the sentence where you've left a blank.

You might say, "You are so *insecure*." To emphasize the annoying aspect of B's behavior, you could use an additional word: "You are so *painfully insecure*."

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/insecure) describes insecure people as "lacking confidence and doubting their own abilities".

Another alternative could be, "You have such low *self-esteem*."

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-esteem) defines self-esteem as "a feeling of having respect for yourself and your abilities". *Low self-esteem* would apply to B, who has no confidence.

Answer (score -2):

You might say "**lackadaisical**" or "**unassuming**" and also "**unassertive**". However, the best might still be "**pusillanimous**", which is not as blunt as "cowardly".

Comment: This response I think has some of the worst suggestions and the best suggestion. "Lackadaisical" is not at all what I'm going for, but "pusillanimous" is pretty close. I think "pusillanimous" carries with it a connotation of contempt, wouldn't you say? Maybe I think so just because I hear "pussy" in the word. I tried to upvote you but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks.